# Convert *.obj to *.arobject for arkit ARReferenceObject

Tags: ios, arkit, object-recognition

I am trying to implement object tracking / object recognition into an application.

I have recently tried ARKit Scanning provided [by apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects) and [vuforia](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Use-Object-Recognition-in-Unity.html) the latter being slightly more efficient.

My problem is that both methods are quite slow at detecting objects and are not very accurate.

Now I am wondering if provided an accurate 3D model in one of the following formats OBJ, STL, USDZ, GLB, DAE, SCN it would be possible to obtain a AROBJECT to be used as an AR Reference for ARKit.

I believe this can significantly improve the quality of object detection, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you have any updates on that, because I have the same problem.

Comment: I didn't find another way to obtain an .obj file for ARKit.

Try Vuforia, in my opinion the engine creates much better point clouds. And since it supports object tracking I find it superior to ARKit. 

This is what I've accomplished with Unity+Vuforia.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVWA4OdT1oY&frags=pl%2Cwn